# What is a probability to choose random subset with no point from A and at least 1 point from B

Tags: probability

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $\Omega$, $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Also $\Omega$ is a finite set, $|A|=|B|=n$, $|\Omega|>>2n$. Suppose we have to choose a random subset of $\Omega$ which has no elements from $A$ but at least 1 element from $B$.

What is the probability of choosing a subset that matches the above requirements if the probability to choose a particular point of $\Omega$ is $p$ (not to choose $1-p$)?

I was told that the answer was something like $(1-p)^n(1-(1-p)^n)$ but I can't understand why it's so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the "universe" $\Omega$ here ? A finite set ? You should bring this precision ?

Comment: @JeanMarie it's a finite set of (suppose) m elements, where m>>2n

Comment: @JeanMarie $\Omega$ certainly must be finite. In any other case if $|A|=n$ and the distribution is not mixed then $\Pr[A]=0$.

Comment: Yes, of course, you can deduce it from the text. But it's better to bring this precision right at the beginning.

Comment: "if the probability to choose a particular point of $\Omega$ is $p$" Thus $p=n/m$?

Comment: @Did it doesn't matter actually, but it's true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of not choose any point of $A$ is $(1-p)^n$. And the probability of choose at least one point of $B$ is $1-(1-p)^n$.

The reason of the second if because the probability of not choose any point of $B$ is $(1-p)^n$, then the complementary probability that is $1-(1-p)^n$ means the probability of choose at least some point of $B$.

In other words

$$\Pr[\text{not choose any point of }B]=(1-p)^n$$

$$\Pr[\text{choose at least one point of }B]=1-\Pr[\text{not choose any point of }B]=1-(1-p)^n$$

Comment: Now I understand! Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Now I understand!" Really? Why the product then?

Comment: @Did because we have to choose them in the same experiment. Therefore, we have to multiply probabilities.

Comment: Mwahahaa... No.

Comment: @Did, I'm not a genius in mathematics, so I could be mistaken. If you think the answer is wrong you can propose your own one.

Comment: It does not require to be a genius to know if one understood an argument or not. But anyway, the main thing that is lacking at present from this page is a precise, explicit probabilistic model. Your question does not provide one (and this OP did their best to answer your question without it, with the unfortunate consequence that some arguments are somewhat lax). Instead of invoking geniuses and the like, you might want to provide one.

Comment: @Did I asked the question because I could not get a grasp on it and received an answer that is sufficient to explain me what I've missed. I think it's enough then.

Comment: Please read my previous comment more carefully: the trouble is that your question is not precise enough, not with this answer which tries to make do (or, you are just evading this fact and then I am not concerned).

Comment: @Did The point is that even with my poorly formulated question I was able to get an answer that is sufficient to my needs. I sincerely sorry for not providing a better formulated question.

Comment: If your needs are not mathematical cogent arguments, you should mention the fact at the start of your question, 'cause many people on the site assume otherwise (silly them...).